# How to Show Div tag only after form submission?

Tags: php, html, forms

How to show div tag only after form submit...?

By using js or php..!

I would like to show the `<div id=submitButton>` after form submission

Div tag code:

```
<script type="javascript">
function onSubmit(){
    document.getElementById('submitButton').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('progressBar').style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<video id='video01'  width='160' height='90' data-autoresize='fit' data-volume=".5"  >
  <source type="video/mp4" src="<?php $data = json_decode($getGP, true); echo $data[1]['file'];?>" />
 <source type="video/mp4" src="<?php $data = json_decode($getGP, true); echo $data[0]['file'];?>" data-quality="hd"/>
</video>

<div id="submitButton">

<button class="button button1" ><a class='afterglow' id="mytrigger" href="#video01">Play Now</a></button>

</div>
```

Html Form Code:

```
<form action="" method="POST" onSubmit="return onSubmit()"return false;>
    <input type="text" size="80" name="url" value="https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMTEPAiVF8t0YqLukflnOSQjwfd8ARIoT2h37AXvYO1uaWodbeiFoBUDuD_19tEbg/photo/AF1QipPA2Bq0JlAR9LoGD3mogsxSb9OZWEG4XqBDD4Rv?key=cjhUT0xrZjM5NGN2SVRLOVptZU5SMUlKV0lQYWpB"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Load Now" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: So only show it if `isset($_POST['submit']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a `JavaScript` implementation you could create a `CSS` class rule to initially hide the `<div id="submitButton">` then within your `onSubmit()` function callback add a CSS class to change the display from `display:none;` to `display:block;` Something along the lines of the following:

```js
function onSubmit(){
  var element = document.getElementById('submitButton')
  element.className += "show-ele";
}
```

```css
.hide-ele {
  display: none;
}

.show-ele {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="submitButton" class="hide-ele">Submit Button Div</div>

    <form action="/" method="POST" onSubmit="return onSubmit()"return false;>
      <input type="text" size="80" name="url" value="<Insert your Video URL here>"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Load Now" name="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

You could then manage the showing/hiding of elements by adding the appropriate `hide-ele` and `show-ele` CSS classes.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
?>

<div id="submitButton">
    <button class="button button1" ><a class='afterglow' id="mytrigger" href="#video01">Play Now</a></button>
</div>

<?php
    }//close if
?>
```